# How can I know which button Index of UIAlertView is clicked when I use UIWebview to make a call

Tags: ios, uiwebview, phone-call

I am able to generate an alert allowing the user to make a call using a `UIWebView` with this code:

```
UIWebView *webV= [[UIWebView alloc] init];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:1834563578"]];
[webV loadRequest:request];
```

However, when I use UIWebView to make a call, the system presents an alert. I want to know which button index the user selected. I don't know how to retrieve the index of the option the user chooses in the alert.

Comment: unable to understand your question

Comment: You can't the `UIAlertView` is handled by the `UIWebView`. If you want to check the result of the `UIAlertView` then use `UIAlertView` and don't load the URL in the webview.

Comment: when i use webview to make a call,The system will present a alertView.I want  to konw which the button index i cliked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for iOS10+.

You can detect a call in `UIWebViewDelegate`:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    if ([request.URL.absoluteString hasPrefix:@"tel:"]) {
        // make a call

        // this method is available in iOS10
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber] 
                                           options:nil 
                                           completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
            // if success is NO, user tap cancel button, or other
            NSLog(@"%d", success);
        }];

        return NO; // the default view will not show
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Set up `UIWebView`:

```
UIWebView *webV= [[UIWebView alloc] init];
webV.delegate = self;
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:1834563578"]];
[webV loadRequest: request];
```

By this, you will know which button tapped depend 
on `success` in `completionHandler`.

Comment: forgive my late,your answer is good ideal,but, if I custom alert view adn action handler, how can I do make call. if  I use system's alert view,the call will start when i cliked the second button.

Comment: OK, that's the question !!!! forgot make a call will alert anothor alert.

Comment: From iOS 10, the `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: options: completionHandler:];` will call `completionHandler` after tap one button in alert.

Comment: Thanks,as if it's a only way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

> Use The following Code.

```
UIAlertAction* cameraButton = [UIAlertAction
                               actionWithTitle:@"Button1"
                               style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive
                               handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {

                                   // do somethingg

                               }];

UIAlertAction *cancelButton = [UIAlertAction
                               actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                               style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                               handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                   //do nothing
                               }];






[alert addAction:cameraButton];
[alert addAction:cancelButton];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```